# How do I pass apikey and other keys to header in guzzle 6.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, guzzle6

I have a simple registration form that the user can register in my app, now I want to send submitted data to another service.

First I test my request using postman as follows using a raw option in a postman panel.

Api url : `app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert`

```
JSON DATA:
{
  "clientId":"w2ncrw06k7ny45umsssc",
  "apiKey":"ssssj2q8qp4fbp9qf2b8p49fz",
  "requestTime":1327056031488,
  "sha":"ba0ddddddb543dcaf5ca82b09e33264fedb509cfb4806c",
  "async" : true,
  "owner" : "adam@rce.com",
  "contact" : { 
        "email" : "test-1@konri.com",
        "name" : "Test",
        "address":{
            "streetAddress":"Brzyczynska 123",
      }
    }
}
```

> UPDATE I get the following success result

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": [],
    "contactId": "b52910be-9d22-4830-82d5-c9dc788888ba",
    "externalId": null
}
```

Now using guuzle htpp request in laravel

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $client = new client();
        $current_timestamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
        try {
            $request = $client->post('app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert', [
                \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS      => array(
                    'debug'        => true,
                    'Accept'       => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'clientId'     => 's255hncrw06k7ny45umc',
                    'apiKey'       => 'sj2q8rt5qp4fbp9qf2b8p49fz',
                    'sha'          => 'ba0br45543dcaf5ca82b09e33264fedb509cfb4806c',
                    'requestTime'  =>  $current_timestamp,
                    'owner'        => 'adwamtrw@fere.com',
                    'http_error'   => true
                ),

                \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
                    'form_params' => [
                        'name'  => $data['name'],
                        'email' => $data['email'],
                    ],
                ],
            ]);  
        }
        catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        }
        $status = $request->getStatusCode();
        $response = $request->getBody();
        $r = json_decode($response);
        dd($r);
        dd($status, $r );
    return $user;
}
```

When I run my app and send the form data I get this using the same data as in postman I get this

```
{#306 ▼
  +"success": false
  +"message": array:1 [▼
    0 => "Not authenticated"
  ]
  +"contactId": null
  +"externalId": null
}
```

It seems like my API key and other header data are not passed to the header as required,

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why `headers` is inside `\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte so can you provide the right way ?

Comment: The first snippet you posted as json data belongs to headers passed to the api or is it the body of the POST request? Because if it is the payload instead of the headers, then you should modify the code below to send the authentication values as part of the body and not the headers as you are doing now in Guzzle.

Comment: @DraQ The above snippets are from API documentation, I just changed and added my API key, sha, etc , and posted it in postman, run post give me success, but in guzzle, I have an error , can you show what you are saying in form of code?

Comment: There is a difference between header and body. How do you fill those information in postman? As header, or as body? If header, then you need to move the `headers` key outside the `\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte check updated codes in qn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Notice that according to the API some values should be passed as headers (Accept, and Content-Type -commonly used as headers, btw-), and other values as part of the body. This is the case of the authentication values like clientId and apiKey.

I don't have guzzle 6 installed at hand but you can try and modify the code to include that data not in the headers section of the request but in the body:

```
$request = $client->post('app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert', [
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS      => array(
            'debug'        => true,
            'Accept'       => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),

        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
            'form_params' => [
                'name'  => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'clientId'     => 's255hncrw06k7ny45umc',
                'apiKey'       => 'sj2q8rt5qp4fbp9qf2b8p49fz',
                'sha'          => 'ba0br45543dcaf5ca82b09e33264fedb509cfb4806c',
                'requestTime'  =>  $current_timestamp,
                'owner'        => 'adwamtrw@fere.com',
                'http_error'   => true
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

I'm not sure about the 'form_params' in under the `RequestOptions::JSON`, but mabye you can put the values directly under `RequestOptions::JSON`.

Comment: I tried this too but unfortunately, I get the same response

Comment: did you try also without the "form_params" level? \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['name'=>"name", ..., ]

Comment: thanks that solve the problem, after removing form params I needed to the API parameter `contact` and pass those form data name, email inside now works

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, not sure what Laravel you're using but there's now [The Laravel HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client) which make this sooo much easier.

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Accept' => 'application/json, application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'clientId' => 'dd2ncrw06k7ny45umce',
                'apiKey' => 'ddjdd2q8qp4fbp9qf2b8p49fdzd',
                'sha' => ' wba0b543dcaf5ca82b09e33264fedb4509cfb4806ec',
                "requestTime" => $current_timestamp,
                "owner" => "testemail@wp.com",
])->post('app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert', [
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
]);

if($response->successful()){
 dd($response->json())
}else{
  // handle yo errors
}
```

Comment: I get the following error `Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: 6.3 I have installed

Comment: The right answer is that you are not supposed to be sending your api credentials in the header, but as data variables as @DraQ says.

Comment: I tried your script but have the above error,  I change already as per @draq